# How do I convert VARBINARY to STRING in javascript?

Tags: javascript, postman

How do I convert VARBINARY to STRING in javascript? (i want use it in Postman Tests)

In sql i can use `select convert(varbinary(40),'Hello World')` to convert string to varbinary

and `select convert(varchar(40),0x48656C6C6F20576F726C64)` to convert varbinary to string

But how do i convert this in postman?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have VARBINARY data type. Do you mean you have a string of a form `'48656C6C6F20576F726C64'`(char codes) and you want to convert char codes back to chars? Take a look [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try if parseINt helps:

```
parseInt(value, baseFrom).toString(baseTo);
```

0x explicitly says its base 16 so you can use parseInt directly as:

```
  parseInt("0x48656C6C6F20576F726C64").toString(2)
```

or

```
  parseInt("48656C6C6F20576F726C64",16).toString(2)
```